# Like Postgresql value up to a point

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

Tell me how to work with the Like operator. I have a table and in the first column there is a value with a dot, but I want to write the value up to a dot in the next column. How can this be done ?

https://dbfiddle.uk/Fv7Opu6u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the like operator.
Try this!

```
UPDATE test SET test_name_2 = SPLIT_PART(test_name_1,'.',1);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tTrKzVEK)